# How do i move an array list from one activity to another?

Tags: arrays, android-studio, android-intent

I have this array of objects in one of my activities, however when I use an Intent and switch to the next Activity, i want to use that same array, how can I do that?
what code do i use in here and what code do i use in the other acitivity?

```
public ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
```

Comment: either declare it as `public static` and call it in other activity or convert it to string attach to intent and convert it back to ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Intent and `putExtra()` methods from your first Fragment then use that intent to navigate then get those extras in your second Fragment.